# Difference between Preact and React rendering stateless components

Tags: reactjs, preact

I am using Preact because i have a project with size constraints. I've created two playground, one with Preact, one with React.

Simply type into the search field, notice how Preact and React update differently. React rerender over the DOM node, Preact adds to it.

I would like Preact to behave like React. Please help

Here is the code in question, playgrounds to see the different behaviors below

```
const handleKeyUp = () =>
  render(
    <div key="1">{Math.random()}</div>,
  document.getElementById('random') 
)

const input = () => 
  render(
    <input onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} placeholder="type somthing here"/>,         
    document.getElementById('input')
  )


input()
```

---

Here is the playgrounds for React:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yey8js?file=index.js

Here is the playground for CodePen:

https://codepen.io/babakness/pen/oEXjPz?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the difference, Preact's render takes a third parameter, which is the DOM node to replace rather than render to.

https://github.com/developit/preact/wiki/Differences-to-React#whats-different